# resize sdwebImage swift

Tags: ios, swift, image-resizing, sdwebimage

Hello I am displaying images on my app using `sdwebImage`. I have a code here to resize the image

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
    let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight))
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

The problem is the above function accepts the UIImage as parameter and `sdwebimage` accepts the URL. How can I call the above resize function in sdwebimage. or in short how Can I resize the image that are presenting through sdwebImage here

```
   cell.profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(UIImage().absoluteURL(profileImageUrl as! String), placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "default-profile-icon")?.circle!, completed: completionBlock)
```

Comment: sdwebimage accept the URL but you applied in that imageview in my knowledge is there no problem

Comment: sorry what does it mean. I am sorry I didn't get you

Comment: in my knowledge in your code is correct , one doubt where you called `resizeImage` method

Comment: yes That is what I am asking. where to call the resize image ?

Comment: The library doesn't support a good way to resize the images. Callback is performed on the main thread and you don't want to resize the images there, the implemented caching will also mean that the resize operation will be needed each time the load  is requested. You'll have to enhance the library to support resizing, one of the better options IMO is to implement your own resizing category similar to the loading category provided by the library.

Answer (score 8):

do like

```
cell.profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(
    NSURL(string: profileImageUrl as! String),
    placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "default-profile-icon"),
    options: nil,
    progress: nil,
    completed: { (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?, cacheType: SDImageCacheType!, imageURL: NSURL?) in

        guard let image = image else { return }
        print("Image arrived!")
        cell.profileImageView.image = resizeImage(image, newWidth: 200)
    }
)
```

Comment: inside the block call that resize method

Comment: your problem is resolved or not, if my answer is not useful reply once i delete my answer

Comment: With your solution resized image will be set to the imageview. but  in chache there is actual sized image so there is still chance  to memory issue. Solution would be image downloader delegate and return resized image like @Evgeny Karev solution

Answer (score 1):

SDWebImage supports image handling directly through its `SDWebImageManagerDelegate` protocol. You can use [`imageManager:transformDownloadedImage:withURL:`](http://imageManager:transformDownloadedImage:withURL:) method to transform the downloaded image.

You can set the image manager delegate like this:

```
SDWebImageManager.sharedManager.delegate = self;
```

Comment: could you please write complete code or edit my code.

Answer (score 1):

Use shared SDWebImageManager is not good idea. Some processes can download images in this time.

My swift 3 example with custom SDWebImageManager in the class and custom SDWebImageManagerDelegate resizer.

```
import SDWebImage

class ImageResizer: NSObject, SDWebImageManagerDelegate {
    private func resizeImage(_ image: UIImage, newHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let scale = newHeight / image.size.height
        let newWidth = image.size.width * scale

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight), false, 0)
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }

    public func imageManager(_ imageManager: SDWebImageManager, transformDownloadedImage image: UIImage?, with imageURL: URL?) -> UIImage? {
        guard let _image = image else {
            return nil
        }

        return resizeImage(_image, newHeight: 20)
    }
}


class BasicTrainView: XibView {
    static let imageManager: SDWebImageManager = SDWebImageManager()
    static let imageResizer = ImageResizer()

    func xxx() {
        BasicTrainView.imageManager.delegate = BasicTrainView.imageResizer
        BasicTrainView.imageManager.loadImage(with: logoURL, options: [], progress: nil) { (image, _, error, sdImageCacheType, _, url) -> Void in
            guard let _image = image else {
                self.carrierLogoImageView.image = nil
                return
            }

            self.carrierLogoImageView.image = _image
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImage has this functionality built in. This is how to use it

```
let imageSize = cell.fanartImageView.bounds.size * UIScreen.main.scale

let transformer = SDImageResizingTransformer(size: imageSize, scaleMode: .fill)

cell.fanartImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: image,
                                options: SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                context: [.imageTransformer: transformer],
                                progress: nil) { (image, error, cache, url) in
    if error != nil {
        // handle error
    }
}
```